# Convert char* to int arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion

I have problem to get int value from char.. here

Serial.println(((char*) "3772837903"));
Serial.println(atoi((char*) "3772837903"));

3772837903
2147483647

anybody can help? thx

Comment: Shouldn't you convert to unsigned int? (not sure)

Comment: That doesn't fit in an `int`. You would also have problems with `int i = 3772837903;`. You need a wider type, or an unsigned int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a 16-bit wide signed variable on AVR-based MCUs. Yours is obviously a 32-bit signed variable so I presume that it's an ARM-based board.

Anyway `4294967296-1` is the maximum for an unsigned integer (`uint32_t`). For `int32_t` it's half of that, i.e. `2147483647`.

And about [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/):

> **Return Value**
>
> On success, the function returns the converted integral number as an int value.
>
> If the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by an int, it causes undefined behavior. See strtol for a more robust cross-platform alternative when this is a possibility.

My guess is that, in practice, this "undefined behavior" will be returning `INT_MAX`.